# Chef Automation - Knife command hanging on unknown host

Tags: linux, automation, chef-infra, knife

I am running a knife command to ssh into all linux machines in chef sever and execute "hostname", but it hangs on an unknown machine, is there some way to find out which machine is causing the hanging? There are over 300 of them..

Knife command im running:

```
knife ssh "platform:oracle" "hostname" -x username -P $password -C 15
```

Output im getting:

```
<name of machine> <hostname>

<name of machine> <hostname>

<name of machine> <hostname>

<name of machine> <hostname>
```

then it hangs, but it doesnt output the name of the machine it is hanging on.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to reduce the timeout to, let's say 5 seconds:

`knife ssh "platform:oracle" "hostname" -x username -P $password -C 15 -t 5`

Depending on the number of unreachable nodes, you should get the culprit after 5 seconds (per unreachable node). Usually with servers in a datacenter (= good connectivity) 1s should be enough.